# Show video stream from Video Server (axis 240Q) to WPF/WINFORM and draw Ellipse on the video (on run time)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, video, video-streaming

I get video via lan from Video Server that bring me the video to my browser.

what I want to do is:
create app in winform or WPF that show the video and to draw on it(on the video control) Ellipse with 1.Location parameter and 2.diameter X 2 (because it`s Ellipse).
thanks.

Comment: Check WPF [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

i think i solve this by use Web Browser Control and draw with GDI(custom control) on it.
what do you think?